# Converting ordinary string to object

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to convert ordinary string like:

```
"Data: {
    id: '288dsbshbdas8dsdsb',
    data: '2pm'
}"
```

to:

```
Data: {
    id: '288dsbshbdas8dsdsb',
    data: '2pm'
}
```

Have tried like that:

```
 string input = "Data: {id: '288dsbshbdas8dsdsb', data: '2pm'};
 var output = Convert.ChangeType(input, TypeCode.Object);
```

But this still returns string?

Comment: It's JSON, not an "ordinary" string. Use [Newtonsoft / Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json).

Comment: Or at least, it's *nearly* JSON. It's not quite valid JSON at the moment.

Comment: Ups, Jon's right. Is it possible to make that valid JSON? @Kertix

Comment: The problem is that I can't quite control input as this comes from outside service. But the structure is always the same.

Comment: If key were single quoted we could simply use Newtonsoft [JsonTestReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm), and there should be a `QuoteChar`  property to specify the Quote char. And a `QuoteName`=False

Comment: An ordinary string is an object. return (object)"Data: { id: 'Some string, not quite JSON', data: 'still an object' }";

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a discussion with the vendor of the outside service. They should be adhering to some kind of standard...

Comment: A webservice that delivers invalid JSON? That would be very odd. If you cannot change that, options are: 1.) Find alternative service that does not have proprietary format. Or 2.) parse yourself :(

Comment: Oh, wait. Do you actually want to work with it or do your really just want it to be `object`? In that case Jodrell is right: you can just cast the whole beast to object.

Comment: No need to cast a string to an object, it already is one.

Comment: I still want to work with it. But it seems that issue is already raised with service to change the format to standard. But meanwhile I think I need to parse it

Comment: Parsing JSON is easy with Newtonsoft provided you have valid JSON. You just create a class with the same properties as the JSON and call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModelType>(myJson)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [NewtonSoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com) [JsonTextWriter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/WriteJsonWithJsonTextWriter.htm), and [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm) You can easly write and read this kind of string.

For writing your must use `JsonTextWriter` property:

```
writer.QuoteName = false;
writer.QuoteChar = '\'';
```

To read to custom configuration is needed.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var objSource= new RootObject{
            Data= new Data{
                id="123456",
                data="FooBar"
            }
        };      

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
        writer.QuoteName = false;
        writer.QuoteChar = '\'';
        serializer.Serialize(writer, objSource);        

        var input= stringWriter.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(input);

        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(input));
        var result = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(reader);

        result.Dump();
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m3T1Ye)

---

Disclaimer: As Jodrell noticed it return a "RootObject".

The writer will return `{Data:{id:'123456',data:'FooBar'}}`
instead of `Data:{id:'123456',data:'FooBar'}` Notice the extra `{}` around the string.
The string manipulation needed to get from one too the other is minor enought.

Comment: This returns `RootObject`, I wonder if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Jodrell, Fixed. From RootObject to Data should be simple. I added a reminder  to wrap the input string into an extra `{}` to make it valid.